# Dealing with no data values

Tags: scikit-learn

During learning, none of my features has '0' values; so I have successfully made my SVM model.

However, when I use that model for prediction with my features, have '0' values in some location of samples. The '0' are no data values. How can I deal with no data values during prediction. I could impute during learning. But if I remove no data value during prediction I will have missing prediction results in those sample locations.

In those sample points, not all features are void but some are.
any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by '0' values? All the features are 0?

Comment: By '0' feature, you mean Null/NaN values or a sparse input matrix?

Comment: @yangjie yeas I mean Null/NaN values. Not all but few features 0. But which features are 0 it varies with the samples.

Comment: @JianxunLi Yes I mean NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some data values are NaN, then you need an imputer to impute those missing values. General strategy is to use 'mean' or 'median' strategy for replacement.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(strategy='mean')
X_data = imputer.fit_transform(X_data_with_missing_values)
```

You can then to fit `SVM` using this imputed `X_data`.